# I want to customize servicechat string resource and image in iOS SDK of live agent chat

Tags: liveagent

I want to customize servicechat string resource and image in iOS SDK of live agent chat, I try to search about example for set data but not found any example.

Therefore, I would like to ask for help with an example code for setting this string if I want to customize.

reference link

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/localization.htm
- https://forcedotcom.github.io/ServiceSDK-iOS/releases/api/234.1/servicechatstringconstants.html#/c:ServiceCloud.Chat.Dialog.General.Title
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/customize_images.htm